# Rails: Form is not being loaded when trying to update

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am just trying to set up a basic application with Ruby on Rails. I have the basic CRUD functions for different entities and with one of them, the form that is supposed to load when the user wants to edit a row does not appear. It knows which ID it needs to edit, it just doesn't load the form.

Link to take you to edit page;

```
<%= link_to 'Edit Review'. edit_review_path(review) %>
```

Controller function;

```
def edit
    @review=Review.find(params[:id])
end
```

HTML Form;

```
    <div class="container">
<h2>Edit Review Details</h2>
<% form_for @review do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :"Profile" %><br />
    <%= f.select :ProfileId, Profile.all.collect {|x| [x.Name,x.id]}, {:include_blank => 'Select Profile'}, class:'form-control'%> <br /><br />
    </div>   
    <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :"Product" %><br />
    <%= f.select :ProductId, Product.all.collect {|x| [x.pName,x.id]}, {:include_blank => 'Select Product'}, class:'form-control'%> 
    </div>   
    <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :"Review Author" %>
    <%= f.text_field :Author %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :"Product Rating" %>
    <%= f.number_field :ProductRating %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :"Review Text"%>
    <%= f.text_field :ReviewText %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :"Date of Review" %>
    <%= f.date_field :DateofReview %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

I have 2 models that have a working update feature and they are the exact same code as this however for this, when I click the button. The page loads but nothing appears other than the text.

[image]

Can someone explain why this is happening? I thought it may be the dropdown boxes but I removed them and still no form loaded up.

Comment: The code inside `<%...%>` is only evaluated. You should use `<%=` to output the form tag. `<%= form_for @review do |f| %>...<% end %>`.

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan I see thank you, I will try it when I boot up the VM next. Will let you know!